# Error no content in "rubric" directive permitted

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

A file I'm trying to add includes a number of rubrics, but I'm getting a strange error with them. I must be doing something stupid but I can't seem to figure it out. Here's my document:

```
==========================
Coding Conventions
==========================

Below is list of coding conventions agreed upon by ________. Please adhere to these conventions to create a more readable codebase!

.. rubric:: Variables

  Variables should be in the ``camelCase`` format in all cases.::

    var = 3
    anotherVar = 4
    moreWordsThanPreviousVar = 5

.. rubric:: Functions

  The same format as Variables, ``camelCase`` should be used.::

    def func():
        #...

    def adheresToCodingConventionFunc():
        #...

.. rubric:: Classes

  Uppercase ``CamelCase`` should be used to repesent classes.::

    class Shape(object):
        #...
    class SquareObject(Shape):
        #...

.. rubric:: Tabs

  Currently CALIPSO uses tabs instead of spaces.::

    var = [1,2,3,4,5]
    for v in var:
        print v        # tab should be 4 spaces long

.. rubric:: General Rules

  No spaces should be left between conditional statements and loops code blocks.::

    if x is not y:
        # ...

    for x in y:
        # ...

  Comments should be right justified when applicable, and only above lines when necessary to explain a section of code(not just one line).::

    var = x - y + r*2           # calculate ___ and place in var
    doFunc(var)                 # do some func with var param
    if var[-1] is not var[:3]:      
        err()                   # error is var does not match criteria
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Turns out I was accidentally indenting my paragraph below the rubric, this is the final document:

```
==========================
Coding Conventions
==========================

Below is list of coding conventions agreed upon by ______. Please adhere to these conventions to create a more readable codebase.

.. rubric:: Variables

Variables should be in the ``camelCase`` format in all cases.::

    var = 3
    anotherVar = 4
    moreWordsThanPreviousVar = 5

.. rubric:: Functions

The same format as Variables, ``camelCase`` should be used.::

    def func():

    def adheresToCodingConventionFunc():

.. rubric:: Classes

Uppercase ``CamelCase`` should be used to repesent classes.::

    class Shape(object):

    class SquareObject(Shape):

.. rubric:: Tabs

Currently CALIPSO uses tabs instead of spaces.::

    var = [1,2,3,4,5]
    for v in var:
        print v        # tab should be 4 spaces long

.. rubric:: General Rules

No spaces should be left between conditional statements and loops code blocks.::

    if x is not y:
        # ...

    for x in y:
        # ...

Comments should be right justified when applicable, and only above lines when necessary to explain a section of code(not just one line).::

    var = x - y + r*2           # calculate ___ and place in var
    doFunc(var)                 # do some func with var param
    if var[-1] is not var[:3]:      
        err()                   # error is var does not match criteria

    # Set the value of var and pass var into a set of functions which calculate things based off var
    var = x - y + r*2
    doAllFuncs(var)
```